# How can I adapt this bash progress bar function for AIX ksh88?

Tags: ksh, aix

I have a bash script for progress bar and I use it when I work in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

prog() {
    local w=80 p=$1;  shift
    printf -v pt "%*s" "$(( $p*$w/100 ))" "";pt=${pt// /.};
    printf "\r\e[K|%-*s| %3d %% %s" "$w" "$pt" "$p" "$*";
}
# test loop
for x in {1..100} ; do
    prog "$x" traitement en cours...
    #sleep .1   # do some work here
#traitement
done ; echo
```

But now I'm using AIX KSH88 and I'm tried to convert this script but I meet several mistakes.
Like :
`pt=${pt// /.}` Bad substitution
 `pt=$(printf "%*s" "$(( 80*20/100 ))" "")`  I get : **printf: bad conversion**

Comment: Mistakes such as?  First adjustment will have to be the `printf -v`, turning into `v=$(printf ...)`. What else? The brace expansion...

Comment: You appear to be logging in with a second account; register and user your [first account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/322130/user322130) to comment on and edit your question.

Comment: I would be easier to rewrite from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function prog {
  typeset w=80 p="$1" pt= IFS=" "
  typeset pc="$((p * w / 100))"
  shift
  while ((pc)); do pt=$pt.; ((pc-=1)); done
  printf "\r\33[K|%-${w}s| %3d%% %s" "$pt" "$p" "$*"
}
# test loop
x=1; while ((x <= 100)); do
  prog "$x" traitement en cours...
  sleep 1   # do some work here
  ((x+=1))
done
echo
```

Comment: I admit to not keeping up with this solution, but if the intention is for the `$p` message ("traitement en cours...") to be on the same line of an 80-column-wide terminal, then I think the length of p needs to be subtracted somewhere.